# SONAR issue "main" should not "throw" anything JAVA 7

Tags: java, exception, sonarqube, program-entry-point, throws

We have this code.  SONAR is complaining about the main() function.
**"main" should not "throw" anything**

*There's no reason for a main method to throw anything. After all, what's going to catch it?
Instead, the method should itself gracefully handle any exceptions that may bubble up to it, attach as much contextual information as possible, and perform whatever logging or user communication is necessary.*

**Q: Would adding a catch(IOException e) {} mitigate this issue?**

```
public class EncryptionHelper {

    private static final int NO_OF_ARGUMENTS = 3;

    /**
     * Ctor
     */
    protected EncryptionHelper() {
        // Empty Ctor
    }

    /**
     * Main
     * 
     * @param args
     * 
     *            0 - Input text to be encrypted or decrypted 
     *            1 - Encrypt/Decrypt [0-Encrypt, 1-Decrypt]
     *            2 - File to write the output
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        if (args.length != NO_OF_ARGUMENTS) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Expected 3 arguments to encrypt/decrypt.");
        }
        OutputStreamWriter fw = null;
        Crypto crypto = CryptoFactory.getCrypto(CryptoType.KBE);
        String en = "";
        if ("0".equals(args[1])) {
            en = crypto.encryptString(args[0]);
        } else {
            en = crypto.decryptString(args[0]);
        }
        try {
            fw = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(args[2]), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
            fw.write(en);
        } finally {
            if (fw != null) {
                fw.close();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try change `public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException` to `public static void main(String[] args)`

Answer (score 1):

> Would adding a catch(IOException e) {} mitigate this issue?

No! I think, that's the worst solution available. By the way, if you would write that, Sonar would complain about the empty catch block - so one issue solved, and one new issue would be the result.

It's more of a design error.

Think about Microsoft Word, or LibreOffice, when you want to open a file, that not exist. (For example you write in the open dialog: `notExistingFile.doc` and press Enter). If there's not a file, called `notExistingFile.doc`, it raises some kind of *exception* (based on the programming language/framework they use).

But instead of, crashing the app, and throw that exception towards, they handle the situation - pop up a window to inform you about the not existent file.

If this is a test-app, or some private project, where you are 100% sure about the file would exist, I would do nothing about it. But if it's a public project, you should handle the exception in some way: write a log about the missing file, inform the user about the missing file (suggest some solution for the problem), etc.

If you want the issue to go away, you should mark that as solved (or hide that issue, there's some way for it). If you'd like to solve it from java code, you should write the following:

```
try {
    // some methods that throw IOException
} catch (IOException ignored) {
    // if you call your variable ignored, Sonar won't complain about it
    // but you should provide some information about this, why did you ignore that exception
    // for developers looking at this code later.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In short, yes. Adding a `catch` block and removing `throws IOException` from the signature would prevent the issue from being raised. But as Nagy Vilmos points out, that doesn't really solve the problem. Because this is a console application, you should use the `catch` opportunity to inform the user of the problem. Yes, barfing the exception out at the user (via `throws IOException`) does that, but it takes so little effort to do that nicely (via `catch` and logging, as recommended by the rule description).